# Why Java Swing pane isn't transparent when it's placed exactly on another panel?

Tags: java, swing

I have `JLayeredPane` with two squares - red on the bottom, and green (transparent) on the top:

[image]

```
public LayeredPaneDemo( )
{
    final JLayeredPane layeredPane = new JLayeredPane();
    layeredPane.setPreferredSize( new Dimension( 200, 160 ) );


    final Rectangle redSquareBounds = new Rectangle( 0, 0, 140, 140 );
    final Rectangle greenSquareBounds = new Rectangle( 50, 0, 140, 140 );


    final JLabel redSquare = new JLabel();
    redSquare.setOpaque( true );
    redSquare.setBackground( Color.RED );
    redSquare.setBounds( redSquareBounds );
    layeredPane.add( redSquare, JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER );


    final JLabel greenTransparentSquare = new JLabel();
    greenTransparentSquare.setOpaque( true );
    greenTransparentSquare.setBackground( new Color( 0f, 1f, 0f, .5f ) );
    greenTransparentSquare.setBounds( greenSquareBounds );
    layeredPane.add( greenTransparentSquare, JLayeredPane.MODAL_LAYER );


    this.add( layeredPane );
}

private static void createAndShowGUI()
{
    final JFrame frame = new JFrame( "LayeredPaneDemo" );
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );


    final JComponent newContentPane = new LayeredPaneDemo();
    newContentPane.setOpaque( true );
    frame.setContentPane( newContentPane );


    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible( true );
}

public static void main( final String[] args )
{
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater( LayeredPaneDemo::createAndShowGUI );
}
```

but when I set green square bound the same as red one, by:

```
greenTransparentSquare.setBounds( redSquareBounds );
```

it seems to be completly covered, and transparency doesn't work anymore:

[image]

Why is that?

Comment: Why did you remove all the code? A question should include a proper [mcve] so that we can just copy/paste and test to see the described behaviour.

Comment: @camickr I saw then someone gave me minus and I thought that this example is too complicated and too long to read. So I tried to provide more MINIMAL example, removing all uncorelated code - if anyone knows how to run Swing application, he can just paste current (relevant) code and run it.

Comment: The "minimal" code should still include the frame and main() methods. We are not here to create our own little Swing application just to test your code. The point of posting code is to make it easy for people to help you. Don't forget to "accept" an answer when you get help so people know the problem has been solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've set your `greenTransparentSquare` to be `opaque`. When you do this Swing assumes that you will paint every pixel within its bounds with a non-transparent colour. The javadoc from `JComponent.paintComponent` has some notes on the consequences of violating the opaqueness contract:

> if this component is opaque, you must completely fill in the background
>   in an opaque color. If you do not honor the opaque property you
>   will likely see visual artifacts.

The blending you're seeing when the green square doesn't fully cover the red square is an *artifact*.

The reason that there's no blending when the green square fully covers the red square is that Swing is optimising away the drawing of the red square — it isn't being painted at all because Swing thinks it is completely obscured.

Simply setting your `JLabel` to transparent won't have the effect you want because background color is ignored when the `opaque` flag is `false` (see the javadoc for `JComponent.setBackground` for notes). You'll have to create your own component and do custom rendering:

```
public static class JSquare extends JComponent {
    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(getBackground());
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    }
}
```